# Can content_tag in Rails be used to pass parameters as text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an `<h1>` or `<p>` element in the HTML file of my Rails project.

This element is used to produce the name of the page. To follow DRY, I want to make this text dynamic by passing the parameters (which correspond to the page's name) to the `<h1>` instead of creating many static pages.

Since I am passing the parameters in the application_controller.rb, I am doing it by setting a category:

```
def set_category
   session[:category] = params[:category] if params[:category].present?
end
```

Now, what I want to do, if the page becomes /history, is to send the history category into the `<h1>`. From reading the documentation, a content_tag seems to be the best way to do this, so I tried:

```
 <%= content_tag :div, data: {session[:category]} do %>
```

No luck there. Any ideas on how to use a parameter as text?

Comment: Try this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at -- do you need something beyond:  `<h1><%= session[:category] %></h1>`. Or, sure, same thing: `<%= content_tag 'h1', session[:category] %>`. The `content_tag` version does the exact same thing as the first one, nothing special. If that's not what you want, explain why it doesn't do what you want, and maybe it'll be more clear what you want. Is it maybe `content_for` you were thinking of instead?  Also, though, I wouldn't use `session` for this in any event.

Comment: you could also just throw into a variable like `@category` and call it in the view

Comment: Hey @jrochkind, both of those worked as content_tags to display the param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best way to implement this. I believe the rails way is to use a helper and [Content_For](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

But for the sake of answering your question here is how your approach would work.

---

I think you may have forgotten the `before_action` filter.

**application_controller**

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action 'set_category'

  def set_category
    session[:category] = params[:category] if params[:category].present?
  end

end
```

The step of setting content of an `<h1>` is like this

**view.erb**

```rb
<%= content_tag :h1, session[:category] %>
```

**OR**

**view.erb**

```rb
<h1>
  <%= session[:category] %>
</h1>
```